# calc relative width in css of portrait (2/3 ratio) and landscape(3/2 ratio) image

Tags: html, css, math, css-calc

I am struggling with maths to find the formula that would allow me to place 1 landscape and 1 portrait image on one line with added padding in a container of random width.

I did manage to get both images to align properly without adding padding but as soon as I do formula stops working. Both images have ratio 2/3 and they are responsive so they remain aligned even when you resize the window, I spent a whole day trying to figure out how to make it work but with no success.

Here is the full code.

```css
.image-landscape, .image-portrait {
  float: left;
}
.image-landscape {
  width: calc(100% * 9 / 13);
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.image-landscape + .image-portrait {
  width: calc(100% * 4 / 13);
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation-float.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="image-landscape">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/831x554/404040/fff&text=1" width="831" height="554">
  </div>
  <div class="image-portrait">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/369x554/404040/fff&text=2" width="369" height="554">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, both div don't have the same height unlike when removing the padding.

How to make both div have the same height with padding?

Comment: What is the issue exactly? adding the padding seems to be fine for me

Comment: try to uncomment in code pen padding-right and padding-left in both classes and you will see that image 1 becomes taller than image 2

Comment: yes it's logical because the width include the padding that are fixed value added to relative ones, so the calc is somehow not accurate

Comment: Exactly and thats what I have a problem with, how to adjust it to make it right ?

Comment: you could  compromise and clip a bit your image and set the height to a fixed value :`img {height:554px;object-fit:cover;}` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVyNQe (you'll loose a few pixels)

Comment: @G-Cyr or we can consider some complex calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation was wrong.

You rate `9 : 4` is correct. Which is equal to `3 : 2 * 2/3`.

What you forgot is `padding`.
For now your `.image-landscape, .image-portrait` css property of `box-sizing` is `inherit`. Which contains `padding` as it's width and height.

So, the height can have offset related your `padding`.

If you put padding as follow for `.image-portrait`

```
padding-left: calc(5px * 4 / 9);
padding-right: calc(20px * 4 / 9);
```

Then both image will keep it's ratio and their height could be same.

But I think you wanted to keep same `padding` for both image.

Please check following `code-snippet`.

```css
.image-landscape,
.image-portrait {
  float: left;
}

.first .image-landscape {
  width: calc((100%) * 9 / 13);
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.first .image-landscape + .image-portrait {
  width: calc((100%) * 4 / 13);
  padding-left: calc(5px * 4 / 9);
  padding-right: calc(20px * 4 / 9);
}

.second {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.second .image-landscape,
.second .image-portrait {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.second .image-landscape {
  width: calc((100% - 50px) * 9 / 13);
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.second .image-portrait {
  width: calc((100% - 50px) * 4 / 13);
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation-float.css">
<div class="row first">
  <h1>1. Padding with Rate</h1>
  <div class="image-landscape">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/831x554/404040/fff&text=1" width="831" height="554">
  </div>
  <div class="image-portrait">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/369x554/404040/fff&text=2" width="369" height="554">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row second">
  <h1>2. Keep Padding</h1>
  <div class="image-landscape">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/831x554/404040/fff&text=1" width="831" height="554">
  </div>
  <div class="image-portrait">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/369x554/404040/fff&text=2" width="369" height="554">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :). `box-sizing` is one of the most useful property in CSS.

Comment: Thanks a lot Алёна

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the padding within the calculation. When you add padding you will decrease the width of the image inside both container by `25px` which will make the height to also decrease but since the ratio is not the same the height will not decrease equally. For the first one it will be `25px * 2/3 (16.67px)` and for the second one it will be `25px * 3/2 (37.5px)`. That's why the first one become taller than the second one.

To fix this we need to either use different padding for both container or change the width calculation. For the second solution, we need to consider decreasing the width of the first one and increasing the width of the second one. let's consider the height difference between both divs which is equal to `37.5px - 16.67px = 5/6 * 25px`. We split this difference: the first div need to decrease by `5/12 * 25px` and the second need to increase by `5/12 * 25px` so that both div will become equal in height.

Then we use the ratio to caclulate the width we need to add/reduce. It's `5/12 * 3/2 * 25px = 5/8 * 25px` for the first one and `5/12 * 2/3 * 25px = 5/18 * 25px` for the second one.

```css
.image-landscape, .image-portrait {
  float: left;
}
.image-landscape {
  width: calc((100% * 9 / 13) - (25px * 5/8));
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.image-landscape + .image-portrait {
  width: calc((100% * 4 / 13) + (25px * 5/18));
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation-float.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="image-landscape">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/831x554/404040/fff&text=1" width="831" height="554">
  </div>
  <div class="image-portrait">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/369x554/404040/fff&text=2" width="369" height="554">
  </div>
</div>
```

The first solution is easier but it won't be good as the other one since we won't have the same padding thus it won't look homogeneous. The idea is to define the padding for one div, calculate the decreasing height then use this height to find the padding for the other div.

Let's keep `25px` of padding in the second div, this will decrease the height of the image by `25px * 3/2` (like previously). Let's define `P` as the padding of the first one and we will have a decreasing by `P * 2/3`. We need both value to be equal which will make `P` to be equal to `25px * 9/4` that we can split in both sides:

```css
.image-landscape, .image-portrait {
  float: left;
}
.image-landscape {
  width: calc(100% * 9 / 13);
  padding-left: calc(20px * 9/4);
  padding-right: calc(5px * 9/4);
}
.image-landscape + .image-portrait {
  width: calc(100% * 4 / 13);
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.row {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation-float.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="image-landscape">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/831x554/404040/fff&text=1" width="831" height="554">
  </div>
  <div class="image-portrait">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/369x554/404040/fff&text=2" width="369" height="554">
  </div>
</div>
```

As we can see the padding for the first div need to be bigger in order to have the same height difference.

**UPDATE**

It's clear that the first solution solve the alignment issue but we have a total width different from `100%` simply because we removed a value and added another value and both aren't equal so we have a total width equal to `100% - ((25px * 5/8) - (25px * 5/18)`. We are then missing `(25px * 25/72)`.

If we need to obtain a total width of 100% we need to consider adding this value by respecting the ratio in order to keep the same icreasing height<sup>**1**</sup>. Let's suppose we want to add `X` to the first and `Y` to the second then we will have those equations:

```
 X + Y = 25px * (25/72)
 X * 2/3 = Y * 3/2
```

After resolving this we will obtain: `Y = 25px * 25/234` and `X = 25px * 25/104`

```css
.image-landscape, .image-portrait {
  float: left;
}
.image-landscape {
  width: calc((100% * 9 / 13) - (25px * 5/8) + (25px * 25/104));
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.image-landscape + .image-portrait {
  width: calc((100% * 4 / 13) + (25px * 5/18) + (25px * 25/234));
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation-float.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="image-landscape">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/831x554/404040/fff&text=1" width="831" height="554">
  </div>
  <div class="image-portrait">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/369x554/404040/fff&text=2" width="369" height="554">
  </div>
</div>
```

<sup>1: I ommited this part initially because I thought it will make the whole caclulation complex and at then we will only have few pixel of difference (`8px`)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, Temani, Could not get my head wrap around the numbers no matter how much I tried.

Comment: I have found a flow with the current calculation, which is not that obvious in the beginning. The images align correctly but their combined width is less than the width of the container. The container is 1200px but combined image columns width is  1191.31px

Comment: in ideal scenario the dimensions should be as follows: `Portrait: W: 354px H: 531px` and `Landscape W: 796 H: 531` as if fyou combine `354px+796px=1150px` it is basically `1200px container` - `50padding` but we actually get  `Portrait: W: 351px H: 527px` and `Landscape W: 790 H: 527` something is by 9px.

Comment: @AndriusSolopovas it's not a flow and I never said that the total width will be 100% :) ... if you check the calculation you will see that we add a value and remove another value that aren't the same, so the summation will not be 100% and to be more precise we have a difference of `25/72 * 25px` and I was aware about it ... if you want we can make it more complicated :p

Comment: @AndriusSolopovas I added the missing calculation ;) but honestly I don't think it worth it unless it will be for one particular case because it's somehow complicated that's why I only did the first part which was already tricky

Comment: Too Complex @AndriusSolopovas. Just need to update `calc((100% - 50px) * 9 / 13)`. This is really simple and it's perfect!

Comment: It's calculation is too bad, I think @АленаВерещака's answer is quiet simple and works perfect!!!

Comment: @FreshFriend this is not *too bad* it's *too math* ;) ... I made all this to explain why he was facing his issue as I don't care a lot about the fix but more about the understanding and the calculation invloved ;) people don't like when it's too complex but it's :)

Comment: I came to a bit more nice solution here how it looks `width: calc(100% * (354 + 25) / (796 + 25 + 354 + 25));` for portrait and for landscape `width: calc(100% * (796 + 25) / (796 + 25 + 354+ 25));`

Comment: I filled 3 A4 papers with various calculations to come to a simple solution which I could not understand from the beginning. Now I feel so stupid... and happy at the same time. Thanks to everyone who took a part in my journey... I could not figure it out without you guys

Answer (score 0):

This way it works with any ratio image as long as height is same in landscape and portrait

```css
.image-landscape {
  width: calc(100% * (796 + 25) / (796 + 25 + 354 + 25));
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.image-portrait {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% * (354 + 25) / (796 + 25 + 354 + 25));
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation-float.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="image-landscape">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/796x531/404040/fff&text=1" width="796" height="531">
  </div>
  <div class="image-portrait">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/354x531/404040/fff&text=2" width="354" height="531">
  </div>
</div>
```